# subquery using DISTINCT and LIMIT

Tags: sql, r, sqlite, subquery

In **SQLite**, when I do

```
SELECT DISTINCT idvar 
    FROM myTable 
    LIMIT 100 
    OFFSET 0;
```

the data returned are 100 rows with (the first) 100 distinct values of `idvar` in `myTable`. That's exaclty what I expected.

Now, when I do

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable 
WHERE idvar IN (SELECT DISTINCT idvar 
                FROM myTable
                LIMIT 100 
                OFFSET 0);
```

I would expect to have all the data from `myTable` corresponding to those 100 distinct values of `idvar` (so potentially the data returned would have more than 100 rows if there is more than one row of each `idvar`). What I get however is all the data for whatever many distinct values of `idvar` that return more or less 100 rows. I don't understand why.

Thoughts? How should I build a query that returns what I expected?

### Context

I have a 50GB table, and I need to do some calculations using R. Since I can't possibly load that much data into **R** for memory reasons, I want to work in chuncks. It is important however that each chunck contains all the rows for a given level of `idvar`. That's why I use OFFSET and LIMIT in the query, as well as trying to make sure that it returns all rows for levels of `idvar`.

Comment: Your description is unclear. What is the difference between what you expect and what you get? Show some examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about SQLite, but in other SQL variants the result of un-ordered LIMIT query is not guaranteed to return the same result every time. So you should also include ORDER BY in there.

But a better idea may be to do a separate query at the beginning to read all of the distinct IDs into R. And then split those into batches of 100 and then to a separate query for each batch. Should be clearer and faster and easier to debug.

Edit: example R code. Lets say you have 100k distinct IDs in variable `ids`.

```
for (i in 1:1000) {
  tmp.ids <- ids[((i - 1) * 100 + 1) : (i * 100)]
  query <- paste0("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE idvar IN (", 
                     paste0(tmp.ids, collapse = ", "),
                  ")")
  dbSendquery(con, query)
  fetch results, etc..
}
```

Comment: I thought of doing this, but then my question is: once I have the data with the distinct values in R (call it a vector `ids`, how do I build the query to select from `myTable` say the first 100 firms in `ids`?